# poner cumple arriba y categoria abajo

Tags: html

Hola buenos dias quisiera que mi select option una apareciera arriba y el otro abajo pero ya e puesto de todo y no me sale osea primero arriba cumple y luego abajo categoria

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
 tds += '<h6 style="color:#0B93A8;"> CUMPLE </h6>';



tds += "<select class='txtFormulario_Pregunta' id='txtFormulario_Pregunta_" + val.idPre + "' rel='" + val.idPre + "'>";
tds += "<option disabled selected>Seleccione</option>";
tds += "<option value='SI'>SI</option>";
tds += "<option value='NO'>NO</option>";
tds += "<option value='NA'>N.A</option>";
tds += "</select>";
                tds += '</div>';
                 tds += '</div>';
                tds += '<div class="col-sm-2 padre">';

                tds += ''

                tds += '<h6 style="color:#3EA1CC;"> CATEGORIA </h6>';



tds += '<select  class="combo1" id="combo1">';
                        tds += '<option title="" value="" disabled selected>Seleccione</option>';
                        tds += '<option title="" value="C">CONDUCTAL</option>';
                        tds += '<option title="" value="S">ESTRUCTURAL</option>';
                        tds += '<option title="" value="O">ORGANIZATIVA</option>';
                        tds += '<option title="" value="AF">OTROS FACTORES</option>';


                    tds += '</select>';



                    tds += '<select class="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria combo2"  id="txtFormulario_PreguntaCategoria_' + val.idPre + '">';
                        tds += '<option disabled selected></option>';

                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title=" Incumplimiento de normas procedimientos y metodos de trabajo"   value="C1">C1</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Falta de uso, mal uso o uso incorrecto de los EPI" value="C2">C2</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Uso indebido los equipos y dispositivos" value="C3">C3</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Posicion inadecuada del cuerpo /postura"  value="C4">C4</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Distraccion / Falta de atencion"  value="C5">C5</option>';
                        tds += '<option data-option="C" title="Falta de señalizacion de peligro"  value="C6">C6</option>';
tds += '</select>';
```

Comment: el problema está en el CSS, y no en el código que has publicado.

Comment: no tengo css en el ajax

Comment: Por favor, me puedes decir ¿que haces con `tds`? Supongo que será el innerHTML de algún elemento HTML. Este elemento, probablemente tiene un estilo. Quieres compartir el css para este elemento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema como te comentó enxaneta es en el CSS de la pagina que carga estos select, una posible solucion es agregar un 'br' al finalizar el primer select para que fuerce el cambio de linea aunque lo mas optimo seria revisar el css.

```
     tds += '<br/>'               
     tds += '<div class="col-sm-2 padre">'  
     tds += '<h6 style="color:#3EA1CC;"> CATEGORIA </h6>';
```

Ademas como al parecer estas usando bootstrap el "col-sm-2" hace que el div flote y se coloque al lado del otro select

**EDITADO**

En el caso de estar usando Bootstrap lo mejor es poner los select en 'row' separados, un row para el primer select

```
tds += '<div class="row">';
tds += '<div class="col-md-12">';
tds += '<h6 style="color:#0B93A8;"> CUMPLE </h6>';
```

y el finalizar este el otro row para el otro select

```
tds += "</select>";
tds += '</div>';
tds += '</div>';
tds += '<div class="row">';
tds += '<div class="col-md-12">';
tds += '<div class="padre">';
......
tds += '</div>';
tds += '</div>';
tds += '</div>';
```

Comment: solo uso la libreria de boostrap

Comment: La solucion que hize era muy facil solo use un tds += '<div class="col-sm-2">'; en el primer select y lo cerraba en el ultimo select gracias por sus ayudas :)

Comment: Eso funciona porque encierras los 2 en la misma celda del grid de bootstrap pero estas diciendo al responsive que los dispositivos medianos en adelante  la columna tendra un ancho de 2 de 12 posibles lo que se vera muy estrecho .. te recomiendo con la misma solucion que lo pongas col-sm-12 y asi dispone del ancho total de la pantalla

Comment: Gracias compañero

Comment: Amigo yoidel este texarea sale de esta funcion como aria para alinearlo a la izquierda
  $(document).delegate('.txtFormulario_Pregunta', 'change', function(event) {
 var valor = $(this).val();
 var idPre = $(this).attr('id').replace('txtFormulario_Pregunta_', '');
        
 if (valor == 'NO') {
  $('#txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre).remove();
  var tds = '<br><br><textarea class="form-control" rows="6" placeholder="OBSERVACIÓN:"  id="txtFormulario_Pregunta_Observacion_' + idPre + '"></textarea>';

Comment: depende de millones de factores entre ellos de a quien le estas agregando este textarea el codigo antes y despues del textarea etc... posible solucion agrega un style="margin-left:5px" al textarea a ver que pasa

Comment: se quedo en la misma posicion amigo ese textarea sale cuando en un select option la opcion sea que no

Comment: Escribeme al correo yoidel86@gmail.com y mandame el codigo a ver si te puedo ayudar asi es muy dificil hacerlo y creo que no es la forma de usar la plataforma. Saludos